# アプリをインストールした時に自動で作成されるショートカットの名前を変更したい

Tags: android

GooglePlayからアプリをインストールした際に、ランチャーのタイトル(アプリアイコンの下に表示される文字)が、ホーム画面とアプリ一覧画面で一致せず困っております。

## したいこと

- ホーム画面に自動作成されるランチャー(ショートカット)のタイトルを、AndroidManifest.xmlの`<application android:label` で設定したものではなく、任意のものにしたい

  - 使っているライブラリの仕様上、`<application android:label`はランチャーのタイトルとは別の文字を設定する必要があるため、手段を調べています

## 現在の状況

AndroidManifest.xml は下記のように実装しています。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.***.***.***">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="application_label"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="activity_label">  //←ランチャーの名前にしたい
        <intent-filter
            android:label="intent_label">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

このアプリをGooglePlayからアプリからインストールすると、作成されるランチャーは下記の通りになります。

#### アプリ一覧画面のアイコン

- アプリ一覧画面に表示されるランチャーのタイトルは、 `<activity>` の`android:label`で設定している **activity_label** になります
- `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` が設定されているactivityのlabelが反映されているため、こちらは意図通りです

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### ホーム画面のアイコン(ショートカット)

- playストアアプリの設定で”ホーム画面にアイコンを追加”をONにしている場合のみ、ホーム画面に自動でショートカットが作成されます。
- このショートカットのタイトルは、`<application>`の`android:label`で設定している **application_label** になります
- ですが、このショートカットのタイトルも`<activity>` の`android:label`で設定している **activity_label** にしたいと考えています

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アプリ一覧画面とホーム画面でランチャーのタイトルが違っているのは混乱を招く恐れがあるので、一致させたいです。
AndroidManifest.xml以外に設定項目があるかもしれないと考え調べましたが、有効な手段が見つけられません。
手段をご存知の方がいらっしゃれば、アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

#### 2018/7/4 追記：

- 使っているライブラリの制約について

サーバにデータをpostするためのライブラリで、
postデータに含ませるアプリ識別ID = AndroidManifest.xmlの`<application android:label`
となり、かつアプリ識別IDは英数字である必要があります。
ただ、ランチャーのタイトルは日本語にしたいため、競合が起きているという状況です。

Comment: 使用しているライブラリの制約であればライブラリの詳細も記載した方がいいと思います。また、どうして同一名ではいけないのか不明なので適当ですがAPI実行のアクティビティとランチャーのアクティビティを分けて起動するアクティビティ名を変更したらどうかと思いました。

Comment: Android では一つのアプリケーションに複数のランチャーアクティビティを持てます。そのためプレイストアアプリがショートカットを作成する際に、特定のアクティビティのラベルではなく、アプリケーションのラベルを参照しているのではないでしょうか？ 根本的にはアプリケーションのラベルを強制するようなライブラリの仕様がまずいのだと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます...！！！
使っているライブラリの制約についてご説明すると、サーバにデータをpostするためのライブラリで、postデータに含ませるアプリ識別ID = AndroidManifest.xmlの`<application android:label`となる仕様です。
かつアプリ識別IDは英数字である必要があるのですが、ランチャーのタイトルは日本語にしたいため、困っております。。
`<application android:label`をアプリ内で２つ持つことが出来ればと思い、ライブラリをAAR(Androidライブラリ)化して、AAR内にもAndroidManifest.xmlを持たせようとしたのですが、最終的にはアプリ自体のmanifestとAAR内のmanifestがマージされてしまい、うまくできませんでした。。